# Android encapper for Rebol R3 scripts

Tags: android, rebol3, r3-gui

Does anyone know how to use [Saphirion's Android encap demo](http://development.saphirion.com/experimental/builds/android/demo-encap.apk)?

I would like to make a single APK from R3/Droid and a Rebol 3 script. I compared `demo-encap.apk` (from the above link) and `r3-droid.apk` but I did not understand the "principle".

Comment: As far as I understand it, the method and tools to do this are not in the public; they are part of Saphirion's intellectual property.  However, you could ask Guiliolunati how he made his apk.

Answer (score 0):

The encapper used by Saphirion for building the Android demo and R3/Droid .APKs is not publicly available. So currently, with publicly available tools, you unfortunately can't encap R3 scripts for Android (or any other platform, for that matter).